# OpenGLRenderer: GL error: Out of memory

Tags: android, memory, opengl-es

I have written an OpenGL ES 3.1 application for Android. It runs fine on Nexus 5X ( Adreno 418 GPU ) , but on Samsung Galaxy S7 ( Mali T880 ) it dies with

```
E/OpenGLRenderer: Error:glFinish::execution failed
E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  Out of memory!
```

in logcat.

Now, I really don't think this is because the application really uses much memory (it only has 1 texture, 2 FBOs the size of the screen, no fonts, nothing else I can think of that would use much memory). At least that's what I *think* the application uploads to GPU.

I would like to debug this without relying on my limited understanding of OpenGL, i.e. it would be best if there was a tool which would show me basic things like

1) the amount of memory available on GPU
2) amount of memory taken
3) taken by what

**EDIT:** I have solved this, with some help from the Mali Graphics Debugger suggested in the comments. It turned out to be a runaway loop in a fragment shader, which under certain circumstances (curiously not arising on Adreno) could keep on looping forever. By 'OUT_OF_MEMORY' I think it meant 'execution of fragment shader takes too effing long'.

Comment: Returning `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` can be a bit of a catch all error for "something has gone wrong" as other error codes have very specific triggering conditions in the specification. It's quite possibly nothing to do with memory allocation at all! Can you share a reproducer?

Comment: Well, the app is quite large (43k lines of code) so a reproducer is probably not going to be a thing of today. If there is no tool to show me what memory is allocated by what, I guess I'll have to carefully remove bit by bit from those 43K lines of code then...

Comment: Developing this app I have found out that Mali GPU is much more strict in its OpenGL ES implementation than Adreno. It is not the first time the app runs ok in Adreno, but fails in mysterious ways on Mali.

Comment: @Leszek You could try using [Mali Graphics Debugger](https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/graphics-development-tools/mali-graphics-debugger) for profiling. I haven't used it myself though, so not sure how much help it would be.